# Deploy SSAS Cube script across multiple cube instances

Tags: ssas

I have an SSAS cube in UAT with multiple changes. I need to now deploy these changes to each cube in live (10+ cubes all with the exact same schema). Then process each cube. What is the best way of doing this?

Currently we do this manually by opening up the changed UAT cube in BIDS, changing the Deployment destination (to point to each live cube), and click Deploy.

Can an SSIS package with a for loop calling an AS Processing Task handle this, for example? Are there XMLA (I don't know much about it) scripts that may be able to?

Thanks!

Comment: Should have rephrased this as: What is the best way of AUTOMATING this.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server Management you can save the process of a cube as an XMLA script. Then you can either process it by executing the script or even create a job in SSMS. [msdn.microsoft SSAS Administrative Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929186.aspx)